# Cheap way to communicate between microcontrollers with rf

Tags: arduino, rf, wireless

Firstly I apologise if this has been answered, I searched and found nothing specific to my question.

Background:

I'm getting married! I would like to create some light boxes for the table names using fibre optics in the shape of constellations (simple enough), I would like to control the LEDs remotely via RF, react to the beat of the music or something similar (not decided yet).

What is the simplest but budget friendly way to make 4-5 Adafruit trinkets (or similar) keep in sync or if I get enough coding time, control independently via a master device (Rpi, Arduino or PC etc)?

I have a handful of the Ebay modules that are about £1 each, terrible things it would seem.  My budget is about £15-£20 per box including any micro controller and other components.  I checked out my usual haunts of Arduino and Raspberry Pi suppliers as well as a good google but found I was flooded by hundreds of products all differing slightly.

Comment: What is "budget friendly"? One man's affordable is another man's fortune.

Comment: Getting married is not budget friendly. How much do you value your time?

Comment: This question shows no research whatsoever. There are literally thousands of products and thousands of examples of how to use them on the Web. Some of them are even specific to Arduino and Adafruit. Come back if you run into a specific problem that we can help you with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this looks quite usable and is already half built: -

[image]

[It's £6.90](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/products/1225257/?grossPrice=Y&cm_mmc=UK-PLA-DS3A-_-google-_-PLA_UK_EN_CatchAll-_-Ad+Group+Catch+All-_-PRODUCT+GROUP&matchtype=&gclid=CjwKCAiAtorUBRBnEiwAfcp_Y4z3lrpjXOCtDimj8V4vVrWpn6wA2GpJ3NrPDqmbFtAmyWES5iwPbxoCSZMQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) from RS in 5 off quantity. Of course if you want to pay about £1 a pair [from ebay](https://www.ebay.co.uk/i/263456055555?chn=ps&adgroupid=13585920426&rlsatarget=aud-295856145004%3Apla-142405565826&abcId=&adtype=pla&merchantid=6995734&poi=&googleloc=1007103&device=c&campaignid=207297426&crdt=0) and get into the design of preambles, protocol and checksum, something like this could be made to work: -

[image]

[Here](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/computing-peripherals/wireless-components-modules/lower-power-rf-modules/) is a link to a number of products from RS that could be used.

Comment: Just to add, the quality (range/noise etc) of those ebay modules is highly variable, even when they look identical

Comment: @BeB00 yes, I wouldn't use them - too much messing around and hair-pulling. RF links are problematic to design really reliable ones.

Comment: The SiLabs module is not only many times the cost of the nRF24's, but operates in frequencies with greater restrictions on what you can do.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yes, these are two very, very different things - different ends of the spectrum and I'm trying to persuade the OP that his time is valuable enough to not bother with ebay rubbish.

Comment: @Andyaka I agree my time is more valuable! I think I will opt for the Zeta 915 DIP, thanks for your suggestion (I don't have the Rep to upvote)

Answer (score 4):

The cheapest way of rf is nRF24L01+ by Nordic semiconductors.
These are 2.4 GHz, range can be high (even without external antenna), as long as you keep the bandwidth/baudrate low. Note to buy the + version, since these are updated/newer. There are also versions where you can add an external antenna, but probably you don't need that.

These have a feature to put 6 in a master/slave mode, you probably need the opposite (1 micro sending to 6 others), but that can be easily been done, by e.g. every second (or more) asking for a response. Maybe something smarter in case you want to use batteries.

Comment: You would probably use one-way unacknowledged broadcasts.  If a slave misses a packet it just catches up with the next.

Comment: The RF24 library is all you need. http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24Network/     ...if you implement the NRF24 Mesh I think it will do exactly what you want. It allows you to send to any one of 5k+ nodes. This Mesh works wonderfully with the small NRF2401+ board without the PA fitted.